# Laravel WebSockets en nWidart Modules

Tags: laravel, websocket

Estoy armando un chat, FUNCIONA TODO PERFECTO... haciendo todo en la base de Laravel, pero cuando utilizo nWidart Modules... solamente funciona el "Usuario está escribiendo" pero no llegan en tiempo real los mensajes!

este es mi Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Modules\IncidentManager\app\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;
 use App\Events\MessageSent;
//use Modules\IncidentManager\app\Events\MessageSent;

class MessageController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    public function sent(Request $request)
    {

        $message = auth()->user()->messages()->create([
            'content' => $request->message,
            'chat_id' => $request->chat_id
        ])->load('user');

        broadcast(new MessageSent($message))->toOthers();

        return $message;

    }
}
```

este es mi archivo Events/MessageSent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('chat.' . $this->message->chat_id);
    }
}
```

y este funciona perfectamente, pero cuando hago el cambio de utilizar
Este -> use Modules\IncidentManager\app\Events\MessageSent;
en lugar de este use App\Events\MessageSent;

Solo llega el "Usuario escribiendo" pero los mensajes en tiempo real dejan de funcionar.

```
<?php

namespace Modules\IncidentManager\app\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class MessageSent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PresenceChannel('chat.' . $this->message->chat_id);
    }
}
```

No muestra error en ningun lado!
y repito, solo deja de funcionar si lo llamo al archivo desde la carpeta de Modules... en la carpeta Events de Laravel funciona sin problemas